# How to display a certain ImageView in a view only when certain buttons from another view are pressed?

Tags: android, imageview, cordova, imagebutton

I have two different layouts, title_bar and bottom_bar. bottom_bar has 3 different ImageButtons: usersButton, activtyButton, and scanButton, and title_bar has a TextView and a couple ImageViews, the ImageView I am interested being refreshButton. here is the xml for bottom_bar:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/bottomToolBar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#000000" 
android:tileMode="repeat"
android:gravity="bottom"  >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/usersButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left" 
    android:layout_weight="2" 
    android:background="#000000"        
    android:src="@drawable/users" />

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/activtyButton"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="left" 
    android:layout_weight="2" 
    android:background="#000000"        
      android:src="@drawable/activity" />

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/scanButton"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:layout_weight="2" 
        android:background="#000000"        
      android:src="@drawable/scan" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And title_bar xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/titleBar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#ff0000" 
android:tileMode="repeat"
android:gravity="top"  >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="43dip"
    android:src="@drawable/top_bar"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/refreshButton"
    android:layout_width="55dip"
    android:layout_height="38dip"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:src="@drawable/bar_refresh"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

What I would like to do is have refreshButton only show up when usersButton and activtyButton are pressed, but not scanButton, but right now it is persisting across all 3 buttons. What I seem to be having difficulty with is seeing where the communication is between bottom_bar and title_bar is regarding regarding which views are displayed, and this is compounded by the use of cordova which acts as a middleman between bottom and title. The java code for bottom bar is:

```
public final class BottomBar implements OnClickListener {

private ImageButton usersButton_;
private ImageButton activityButton_;
private ImageButton scanButton_;
private Activity activity_;

public BottomBar(LinearLayout layout, Activity activity) {
    activity_ = activity;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout bottomBar = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.bottom_bar, null);

    layout.addView(bottomBar);

    usersButton_ = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.usersButton);
    activityButton_ = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.activtyButton);
    scanButton_ = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.scanButton);

    usersButton_.setOnClickListener(this);
    activityButton_.setOnClickListener(this);
    scanButton_.setOnClickListener(this);

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    FrameLayout titleBar = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.title_bar, null);

    layout.addView(titleBar, 0);

    ImageView backButton = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.backButton);
    backButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

public void onClick(View view) {
    Log.d("getClass", activity_.getClass().getName());

    if (activity_.getClass().getName().contains("CameraActivity")
            || activity_.getClass().getName()
                    .contains("RedemptionActivity"))
        activity_.finish();

    String app_name = ((App) activity_.getApplication())
            .getAppName();
    Log.d("app name", app_name);

    if (view == usersButton_) {
        Log.d("onClick", "usersButton");
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.sampleapp.LOAD_URL");
        intent.putExtra(
                "url",
                "file:///android_asset/www/index.html#activeTab=Tab%253ATerm%253A1&_=GenericScreen&limit=30&offset=0&page=TabbedPage%253ATerm%253A1&app_name="
                        + app_name);
        activity_.sendBroadcast(intent);
    } else if (view == activityButton_) {
        Log.d("onClick", "activityButton");
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.samplepp.LOAD_URL.LOAD_URL");
        intent.putExtra(
                "url",
                "file:///android_asset/www/index.html#activeTab=Tab%253ATerm%253A2&_=GenericScreen&limit=30&offset=0&page=TabbedPage%253ATerm%253A2&app_name="
                        + app_name);
        activity_.sendBroadcast(intent);
    } else if (view == scanButton_) {
        Log.d("onClick", "scanButton");
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity_, CameraActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        activity_.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

}

java code for title_bar:

```
public class Title extends CordovaPlugin {
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
        final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    Log.d("Title", action);
    if (action.equals("change")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.sampleapp.CHANGE_TITLE");
        intent.putExtra("title", args.getString(0));
        this.cordova.getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

and finally java code for cordova:

```
public class Cordova extends DroidGap {
TextView title;
ImageView backButton;
ImageView refreshButton;

private void changeTitle(String url) {
    if (url.contains("Term%253A1"))
        title.setText("App Users");
    if (url.contains("Term%253A2"))
        title.setText("User Activity");

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);

    registerReceiver(mHandleUrlReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            "com.sampleapp.LOAD_URL"));

    registerReceiver(mHandleTitleReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            "com.sampleapp.CHANGE_TITLE"));

    this.init();

    this.appView.clearCache(true);
    this.appView.clearHistory();

    new BottomBar(this.root, this);

    backButton = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.backButton);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            appView.goBack();
            backButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            changeTitle(appView.getUrl());
        }
    });

    /*refreshButton = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);
    refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });*/

    title = (TextView) this.root.findViewById(R.id.title);

    spinnerStart("Loading", "Please wait...");

    if (this.getIntent().hasExtra("json")) {
        String json = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("json");
        Log.d("CORDOVA JSON", json);

        try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(json);
            Log.d("CORDOVA JSON", jObject.getString("app_name"));
            ((RobotFruitMerchant) this.getApplication())
                    .setSessionId(jObject.getString("session_id"));

            String url = "file:///android_asset/www/index.html#activeTab=Tab%253ATerm%253A1&_=GenericScreen&page=TabbedPage%253ATerm%253A1&limit=30&offset=0&sessionId="
                    + jObject.getString("session_id")
                    + "&userId="
                    + jObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("id")
                    + "&app_name=" + jObject.getString("app_name");
            super.loadUrl(url);
            title.setText("App Users");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSONException", e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    } else {
        String url = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
        super.loadUrl(url);
    }

}

private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleUrlReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String url = intent.getExtras().getString("url");
        Log.d("CordovaReceiver", url);
        appView.loadUrl(url);
        changeTitle(url);

    }
};

private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleTitleReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String title_text = intent.getExtras().getString("title");
        title.setText(title_text);
        backButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
};

}
```

Sorry if it's a little verbose, I'm relatively new and wanted to be as specific as possible. Any hints/suggestions/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think I found a workaround. What I did was declare refreshButton as a public static int so that it would be accessible by other classes, and then call BottomBar.refreshButton.setVisibility(View.GONE) in the CameraActivity class that is called when scanButton is pressed. It seems to work for the time being, but I'm not sure how safe or practical it is in general. If anyone has a better method, or reasons why I shouldn't do it this way, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I created a public mutator method in BottomBar.java that accesses the refresh_button imageButton, and just call that in Cordova.java. Seems to be safer than a public static variable.